# Getting 'unregistered datatype' error in QML when Q_GADGET struct is in a separate header file

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qml, qgadget

I have a custom `struct` which I use as a `Q_PROPERTY` type in a `QMediaPlayer` derived class. But here's the code:

```
struct VideoMeta
{
    Q_GADGET

    Q_PROPERTY(int width MEMBER width)
    Q_PROPERTY(...)
    ....

public:

    int width;
    ...
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(VideoMeta)

class FrameProvider : public QMediaPlayer
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(VideoMeta videoMeta READ getVideoMeta WRITE setVideoMeta NOTIFY videoLoaded)

    VideoMeta m_videoMeta;

    ...
}
```

And I use it in a `Label`:

```
Label {
    text: "Cached frames: " + cacheLoaded + " / " + frameProvider.videoMeta.framecount
}
```

This works like charm but here comes the twist:
If I copy and paste the declaration of the `struct` into a separate header file (and obviously included it) with the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro, I get the following error:

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'VideoMeta' for property 'FrameProvider::videoMeta'
```

So I have two questions:

1. The less important: Why do I need to use the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro, if the [documentation says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) that I don't need it with the `Q_GADGET` macro because it automatically registers the type?
2. The more important: Why can't I move the declaration into an other header file? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This might be relevant:
I use Qt v5.15 in a Visual Studio (MSVC v142) project. (Not in Qt Creator.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q_GADGET` main usage is to allow a non QObject type to have introspection.

> The Q_GADGET macro is a lighter version of the Q_OBJECT macro for
>   classes that do not inherit from QObject but still want to use some of
>   the reflection capabilities offered by QMetaObject. Just like the
>   Q_OBJECT macro, it must appear in the private section of a class
>   definition.
>
> Q_GADGETs can have Q_ENUM, Q_PROPERTY and Q_INVOKABLE, but they cannot
>   have signals or slots.
>
> Q_GADGET makes a class member, staticMetaObject, available.
>   staticMetaObject is of type QMetaObject and provides access to the
>   enums declared with Q_ENUMS.

It does not say anything about registering the type.

Also `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` does not register a type, but declares it.

To register `VideoMeta` you need to call `qRegisterMetaType<VideoMeta>()`.
Qt documentation specifically states that `qRegisterMetaType<T>()` must be called for a type to work in the Qt property system.

> Also, to use type T with the QObject::property() API, qRegisterMetaType() must be called before it is used, typically in the constructor of the class that uses T, or in the main() function.

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1

Comment: Calling the `qRegisterMetaType` in the `main()` function solved my problem! Thank you! But I still don't understand why I need to call this function when the declaration is in an other file and why I don't need it when they're in the same compile unit. And I know that `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE ` doesn't register a type but the documentation says "Some types are registered automatically and do not need this macro" then lists some cases and one of them is "Classes that have a Q_GADGET macro". Anyway... it works and that's all what matters. Thanks again!

Comment: @FenyvesiAttila Given the sentence "Some types are registered automatically and do not need this macro", I'd say that "registered" is improperly used here and means "declared" as it is talking explicitly about the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro, not the qRegisterMetaType function.